# Combining inequalities to not have coefficients

Tags: inequality, summation, algorithms, constraints

We have in input an inequality *cons* and a set of inequalities *C* and we want to find a way to sum them and simplify in a way that no variable has a coefficient and that the number of constraints that we took is maximal.

The input is always a constraint without any coefficient and it is always a `<= k` for a given `k`.

For example we can have in input:

```
cons = x1 + x2 + x3 <= 1
C:
   c1 = x1 + x2 + x4 <= 1
   c2 = x1 + x5 <= 1
   c3 = x3 + x4 <= 1
```

- If we sum: `cons + c1`, we obtain `2x1 + 2x2 + x3 + x4 <= 2` and we do not respect the condition that no variable should have a coefficient.
- If we sum `cons + c2`, we obtain `2x1 + x2 + x3 + x5 <= 2`, so again it is not working.
- If we sum `cons + c3`, we obtain `x1 + x2 + 2x3 + x4 <= 2`, so again it is not working.
- However, if we sum `cons + c1 + c3`, we obtain `2x1 + 2x2 + 2x3 + 2x4 <= 3`, thus it is `x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 <= floor(3/2)`, and this time it works.

Does it exist an optimal way to solve this problem except going through all the possibilities?

Does this problem has a name in the literature?

Comment: It's not clear to me that it's possible in general. For example, take $C = \{2x_1 + 3x_2 \leq 1\}$. Clearly nothing that we can do is going to get rid of those coefficients. So whatever general method you hope to find must make some use of whatever special properties those situations where it is possible have. A good first step, then, would be to determine when that happens. Secondly, note that the inequality is entirely irrelevant to the whole question: you're just talking about taking linear combinations of vectors to obtain a vector whose entries are all 0 or 1.

Comment: I will add more information but first: it is always a sum of variables without coefficient lower or equals than k. (xi + xj + ... + xn <= k). So the case "2x1 + 3x2 <= 1" cannot arrive. Thus, it the 'worst' case, I will just not perform any sum and return the input as it arrived.

An extremely good point regarding the linear combinations of vectors, I will try to think in this way.

Comment: In that case, $2x_1 + 3x_2 \leq 1000$. Again: $k$ is irrelevant. All of my comments still hold: any solution that you have *must* start by checking if it's possible, then exercise whatever special properties those vectors for which it works have that others don't. Start by finding out for which vectors it is possible.

Comment: Sorry, I was probably unclear. I meant that at the beginning, there are no equations with a coefficient, they all start with 1*x1 + 1*x2 + .... <= k. We cannot start with "2*x1 + 3*x2". So at the beginning, all vectors are possible